# "pip install line_profiler" fails

Tags: python, pip

I type

```
sudo pip install "line_profiler"
```

and I get

```
Downloading/unpacking line-profiler
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement line-profiler (from versions: 1.0b1, 1.0b2, 1.0b3)
Cleaning up...
No distributions matching the version for line-profiler
Storing debug log for failure in /home/milia/.pip/pip.log
```

When I search for line_profile using

```
sudo pip search "line_profiler"
```

I get:

```
django-debug-toolbar-line-profiler - A panel for django-debug-toolbar that integrates
                        information from line_profiler
line_profiler             - Line-by-line profiler.
tracerbullet              - A line-by-line profiler that doesn't suck.
```

Somehow the underscore gets turned to "-". How can I bypass that?

Comment: `pip install line_profiler` without the quotation marks

Comment: Same result as with the quotation marks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem is not in the fact that `pip` converts `_` into the `-` to meet the package naming requirements, but the thing is: the package is in `beta` state, there is no stable package versions. In other words, there are only `beta` package version links available on the [package PyPI page](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/line_profiler). As you see, `pip` sees it:

```
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement line-profiler (from versions: 1.0b1, 1.0b2, 1.0b3)
```

According to the [Pre-release Versions](http://pip.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/pip_install.html#pre-release-versions) documentation page:

> Starting with v1.4, pip will only install stable versions as specified
>   by [PEP426](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0426) by default. If a version cannot be parsed as a compliant
>   [PEP426](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0426) version then it is assumed to be a pre-release.

Pass [`--pre`](http://pip.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/pip_install.html#install-pre) argument to the `pip install`:

> --pre
>
> Include pre-release and development versions. By default, pip only finds stable versions.

```
sudo pip install --pre line_profiler
```

Or, install a specific version:

```
sudo pip install line_profiler==1.0b3
```

Answer (score 2):

I installed miniconda and run these:

`$ conda install -c anaconda line_profiler`